# How to emulate integrated numeric keypad cursor keys in linux

Tags: linux, numeric, keypad, emulation, integrated

On many older laptops and some compact keyboards there is an [integrated numeric keypad](http://www.pctips.smittystips.com/v_enable_laptop_numpad.php) in the main keyboard area.  This alternate keypad is activated with a special 'Fn' key next to the left Ctrl key.

As a programmer I learned to use the cursor movement keys (arrows, PgUp, PgDn etc.) and found it greatly improved my programming speed.  And the benefits were not bound to just a single application as is the case with specialised shortcut keys.

On conventional PC keyboards, the 'Windows Key' can be used to emulate the 'Fn' key and a corresponding integrated numeric keypad.  When I used to use MS Windows I found [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) was able to map the keys using [a simple script](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/10624-winkey-as-fnkey/).

Recently I learned about xkb and how it can be used to [map keystrokes at a very low level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753190/how-to-get-numeric-keypad-arrows-working-with-java-applications-on-linux).

**What is the xkb keyboard mapping profile that will emulate an integrated numeric keypad using the windows key as the fn key?**

Hint(?): I suspect the file will look a lot like the '*/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/keypad*' file on a Debian-derivative linux distro.  This 'keypad' file is included at the top of the '*/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc*' file.

The [corresponding autohotkey script](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/10624-winkey-as-fnkey/) for reference (# == WinKey):

```
#8::Up
#k::Down
#u::Left
#o::Right

#7::Home
#j::End
#9::PgUp
#l::PgDn

#m::Insert
#.::Delete

;(Scroll with the left-over keys)
#i::WheelUp
#,::WheelDown
```

Note that all these keys need to work with **any combination of Ctrl, Alt, Shift** as well as the Windows Key.

Comment: I've made some progress on this but I lack the expertise with xkb.  A more specific, [related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236089) has been asked on the unix site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to install numeric keypad-like cursor keys on the main keyboard in Linux / XKB...

1. *xkbcomp $DISPLAY original.xkb* (just in case ;)
2. *xkbcomp $DISPLAY custom.xkb*
3. Edit custom.xkb
4. Add the following at the end of section: xkb_types "..." {

   > ```
   > type "WinKeyAsFnKey" {
   >   modifiers = Shift+Super;
   >   map[Shift] = level2;
   >   map[Super] = level3;
   >   map[Super+Shift] = level3;
   >   level_name[Level1] = "Base";
   >   level_name[Level2] = "Caps";
   >   level_name[Level3] = "Fn";
   > };
   > ```
5. Add the following at the end of section xkb_symbols "..." {

   > ```
   >  key <AE07> {type="WinKeyAsFnKey",symbols[Group1]=[7,ampersand,NoSymbol],actions=[NoAction(),NoAction(),RedirectKey(key=<HOME>,clearmods=Super)]};
   >  key <AE08> {type="WinKeyAsFnKey",symbols[Group1]=[8,asterisk,NoSymbol],actions=[NoAction(),NoAction(),RedirectKey(key=<UP>,clearmods=Super)]};
   >  key <AE09> {type="WinKeyAsFnKey",symbols[Group1]=[9,parenleft,NoSymbol],actions=[NoAction(),NoAction(),RedirectKey(key=<PGUP>,clearmods=Super)]};
   >  key <AD07> {type="WinKeyAsFnKey",symbols[Group1]=[u,U,NoSymbol],actions=[NoAction(),NoAction(),RedirectKey(key=<LEFT>,clearmods=Super)]};
   >  key <AD09> {type="WinKeyAsFnKey",symbols[Group1]=[o,O,NoSymbol],actions=[NoAction(),NoAction(),RedirectKey(key=<RGHT>,clearmods=Super)]};
   >  key <AC07> {type="WinKeyAsFnKey",symbols[Group1]=[j,J,NoSymbol],actions=[NoAction(),NoAction(),RedirectKey(key=<END>,clearmods=Super)]};
   >  key <AC08> {type="WinKeyAsFnKey",symbols[Group1]=[k,K,NoSymbol],actions=[NoAction(),NoAction(),RedirectKey(key=<DOWN>,clearmods=Super)]};
   >  key <AC09> {type="WinKeyAsFnKey",symbols[Group1]=[l,L,NoSymbol],actions=[NoAction(),NoAction(),RedirectKey(key=<PGDN>,clearmods=Super)]};
   >  key <AB07> {type="WinKeyAsFnKey",symbols[Group1]=[m,M,NoSymbol],actions=[NoAction(),NoAction(),RedirectKey(key=<INS>,clearmods=Super)]};
   >  key <AB09> {type="WinKeyAsFnKey",symbols[Group1]=[period,greater,NoSymbol],actions=[NoAction(),NoAction(),RedirectKey(key=<DELE>,clearmods=Super)]};
   > ```
6. Save custom.xkb
7. *xkbcomp custom.xkb $DISPLAY*

I'm still working on the mouse scroll with 'i' and ','.

**EDIT**:
The above solution does **not** play nice with Google Chrome and Chrome-based apps (like Slack).

Alternative approach is to use a programmable keyboard.  I use an [after-market PCB for a CoolerMaster Masterkeys S keyboard](https://www.1upkeyboards.com/shop/controllers/unloved-bastard-controller/).  The [Easy AVR](http://dhowland.github.io/EasyAVR/build/html/) layout is [available online](https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/freshcode_public/winkeyasfnkey/easyavr-keymap/cm-masterkeys-s/) (although currently the left win-key now doesn't work by itself...I use the right one).